# Jersey client can't deserialize the XML output: message body reader was not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jersey

I'm using the old `com.sun.jersey.jersey-client@1.19.4` library to invoke a POST on a private third-party REST service, using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

Everything seems to behave just as expected, however, the response isn't being automatically deserialized to my POJO. The exception is a `ClientHandlerException`, claiming there's no message body parser for that POJO.

The available default providers are:

> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

The expected third-party service XML output template:

```
<foobar>
    <foo>Foooooooo</foo>
    <bar>Barrrrrrr</bar>
</foobar>
```

The POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foobar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foobar {

    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    private String foo;

    @XmlElement(name = "bar")
    private String bar;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

The request:

```
MultivaluedMap parameters = new MultivaluedMapImpl();

parameters.add(...);

Foobar response = client.resource(URL)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .post(Foobar.class, parameters);
```

The exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body
>   reader for Java class foo.bar.Foobar, and Java type class
>   foo.bar.Foobar, and MIME media type text/html; charset=UTF-8 was not
>   found     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:630)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
>     at foo.bar.Main.jerseySample(Main.java:103)     at
>   foo.bar.Main.main(Main.java:109)

Using the JAXB unmarshaller to deserialize the XML string works just fine, however Jersey can't do it on it's own (perhaps with the help of `XMLJAXBElementProvider`, `XMLRootElementProvider`, `XMLRootObjectProvider`?). What's going on here?

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha added. However, I just noticed the server replies a `text/html; charset=UTF-8` for its content-type, instead of `application/xml`. Is there a chance this is the issue? If so, will I need a custom `MessageBodyReader`?

Comment: Yea, if the server is sending you XML and the has the content-type header as text/html, that's a problem. A MessageBodyReader will not be found for this. The correct content-type header should be application/xml. This header is where they get the `text/html` part of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way I found to solve this problem is to create a custom `MessageBodyReader`.

```
public static class FoobarMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Foobar> {

    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public RespostaIncluirMessageBodyReader() throws JAXBException {
        unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foobar.class).createUnmarshaller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type.isAssignableFrom(Foobar.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Foobar readFrom(Class<Foobar> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            return (Foobar) unmarshaller.unmarshal(entityStream);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not unmarshal the XML output", e);
        }
    }

}
```

...and add it to the client configuration, like this:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getClasses().add(FoobarMessageBodyReader.class);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

You should now have your object deserialized successfully.